# How to align listitems to the right, on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

[look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuEqj.png)

I am developing a web site and I would like to know how can I align two list items (sign up and log in) to the right of the web site, while keeping the others in place?

I am using pug.

```
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
   ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li
      a(href="#") Product
    li
      a(href="#") Features
    li
      a(href="#") Pricing
    li
      a(href="#") Blog
    li
      a(href="#") Contact Us
    li
      a(href="sign-up") Sign Up
    li
      a(href="#") Login
```

Comment: Include your codes in the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Include the code as code, not as an image. Also both those images seem to be showing the same code.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap V4?

Comment: I am using The newest one

Comment: Bootstrap V4? You'd know if that's what you were using. Very different from older versions, still in Alpha.  Need to know to give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstap 4**

If you using Bootstrap V4, this is fairly straightforward. You simply need to apply the `.navbar-toggler-right` modifier class. By default it's responsive, so will only display right on larger screens, and stacked on mobile devices.

```
nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable-md
  .collapse.navbar-collapse
    ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto.mt-2.mt-lg-0
      li
        a(href="#") Product
      li
        a(href="#") Features
      li
        a(href="#") Pricing
      li
        a(href="#") Blog
      li
        a(href="#") Contact Us
    ul.my-2.my-lg-0
      li
        a(href="sign-up") Sign Up
      li
        a(href="#") Login
```

Read more,  The [Bootstrap Documentation on Navbar](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

---

**Bootstrap 3 (latest stable version)**

If you r using the latest stable version of Bootstrap, or anything below 4, then this is even easier. Just define your right-alligned `ul` like this `ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right`

```
nav.navbar
  .container-fluid
    ul.nav.navbar-nav
      li
        a(href="#") Product
      li
        a(href="#") Features
      li
        a(href="#") Pricing
      li
        a(href="#") Blog
      li
        a(href="#") Contact Us
    ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      li
        a(href="sign-up") Sign Up
      li
        a(href="#") Login
```

Read more, W3Schools have a [tutorial about Bootstrap navbars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)